# Alignment of file scope variables

Tags: c, visual-studio

I found a source where the author makes assumptions about the alignment and order of variables like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
int a;
char b;
char c;
#pragma pack(pop)

void foo(FILE *f)
{
    fwrite(f, &a, 6);
}
```

I know packing pragmas in the context of structures. But can this also be used for file scope variables? In the case that this works for the given compiler, is that defined in the C standard?

Comment: Additional to your question, I would ask something else: How the author will ensure that the allocated variables `a`, `b`, and `c` will have exactly this order in the binary? (AFAIK, this is not granted by the standard.) Otherwise, the `fwrite(f, &a, 6);` does not the expected even if `sizeof a + sizeof b + sizeof c` is 6. I would at least bundle `a`, `b`, and `c` in a `struct`. (No, actually, I wouldn't dare to do such hackish things...) ;-)

Comment: I googled a bit and found [gcc: 5.52.7 Structure-Packing Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html), [VS2015: pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx), [IBM: #pragma pack](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.cbclx01/pragma_pack.htm). 1. GCC mentioned explicitly to provide the pragma for compatibility to MS. 2. All 3 mentioned structures (or aggregates) explicitly. 3. `#pragma`s are in general for non-standard extensions, aren't they?

Comment: The C standard recognizes (defines) `#pragma`, but the standard doesn't define any packing pragmas.  Consequently, the behaviour of `#pragma` is up to the compiler.  If the compiler doesn't recognize the directive, it must ignore it — that's all.  So, read the compiler manual.  Don't assume it will work the same for any other compiler (though it might).  Certainly, the C standard doesn't legislate what it means.

Comment: The C standard doesn't guarantee the ordering here. In fact, since a, b, c here have external linkage it would be impossible to guarantee their ordering because another translation unit could define them in another order. So packing here is very compiler specific and probably a terrible idea to begin with. (add another file to your compilation that has the same three variables with pragma pack, but the variables are in a different order, see what happens).

Comment: @Art The variables a,b,c are defined in the current translation unit. If they were defined elsewhere you would get a linker error about duplicated symbols. So I don't agree your concern that "another translation unit could define them in another order".

Comment: @harper C11 6.2.2: "In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an entire program, each declaration of a particular identifier with external linkage denotes the same object" and "If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external."

Comment: @harper The point being that another translation unit could have _declared_ them in another order - which may drive the eventual order.  Many possibilities including putting all `char` in one segment and all `int` in another.  Make a `struct` would be a first step keeping them together and in order.  - yet maybe not packed.

Comment: @Art Your cites from C11 6.2.2 regards declaring identifiers external. The actual instances are **defined** once, in one compilation unit. This is the only place where the order and alignment can be defined. As you wrote, other comp. units can have different ideas about order. That's why the compiler/linker must make **one** decision.

Comment: @harper You're mixing up "storage class specifiers" (static, extern, or nothing) and "linkage" (internal, external, none). And the second part I quoted is very clear. If you don't have a storage class specifier on an object, then its linkage is external. In older/linker terminology this is called "commons". If your compiler complains about duplicated symbols for objects then your compiler is not a C compiler. (I also double checked, the same words are used in C89, so if visual studio complains, it is not even compatible with ANSI C).

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect (but can't prove) that the `#pragma` directives in the posted code fragment are meaningless.  The compiler would have made a note to pack any structure declarations it found, but it didn't find any.  (And this is not the sort of thing I would expect the compiler to warn about.)

The code worked (if it worked) by accident, not because the `#pragma` directives ensured it.

The behavior of specific `#pragma` directives is compiler-dependent, but it's safe to say that, no, packing pragmas can *not* be used for file-scope variables.

Needless to say, the idiom expressed in the posted code fragment is a terrible, terrible idea, and should not be relied on even if it seems to work.  If it works, it works for the wrong reasons, and there are altogether better ways of accomplishing the same task.

Comment: *Needless to say, the idiom expressed in the posted code fragment is a terrible, terrible idea*  IMO using the word "idea" to characterize the code as posted, even with the addition of multiple instances of "terrible", is too kind.  Words well beyond "brain fart" come to mind...